# Getting Error: Listener currently does not know given SID when using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Please see screenshot:

[image]

I was successfully connected using SQL*Plus.

[image]
[image]

But when I trying to connect same database using same user using SQL Developer, then I'm getting error. Anyone have any idea  ? I see all services running fine.

**tnsnames.ora**

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Is it a local database or remote?

Comment: Look for file `Tnsnames.ora` and edit your question with its content

Comment: Instead of `orcl` try the full connection string, i.e. `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))`. However, this is just a workaround, proper solution is to fix your `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: or you can simply `sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl`

Comment: Your first SQL\*Plus connection got ORA-12505, which may be because the database started after the listener (it can take a minute to register the SID), or it can't register at all. The second successful connection does not have the TNS data so it local (connecting directly to whatever your ORACLE_SID is set to) and bypasses the listener (or is remote to somewhere else and you have TWO_TASK set). My first guess would be that your listener isn't on 1521; can you run `lsnrctl status` and add the text of that (not an image) to the question?

Comment: Well no, you must have the listener on localhost:1521 or you wouldn't get the SID error... oops. The DB may still not be registered but that wouldn't explain the SQL Developer error. Can you confirm the SQL Developer error was after the listener started? The listener status may still be useful.

Comment: localhost is still defined as 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file, right?

Comment: yes..that is defined as localhost

Comment: There would be value in checking the listener log status (e.g. make sure it is enabled...or enable it using this command, lsnrctl SET LOG_STATUS {on | off}). Also, there would be value examining the listener log file during this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Write

**orcl** in **SID**, not service name.

I think it will be good idea :)

Comment: If that was the only problem then it would report an 12505 still, but referring to SERVICE_NAME in the message instead of SID.

Comment: what is the listener servicing? run this from your CMD window
 lsnrctl -status

You could also try the BEQUEATH connection option - that bypasses the listener and goes straight in, just like SQL*Plus when on the same machine as the database